# aws appsync connection does not bring back items from all models

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I created a schema using the amplify cli and everything works as expected. The problem is when i try to perform a query on the events model it brings back comments as being null even though the event has comments. What confuses me more is when i query the comments alone they bring back their respective events but same thing does not work when i query for events. **This is my schema below:**

```
  type Event @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  latitude: Float!
  longitude: Float!
  startDate: String!
  endDate: String!
  description: String!
  coverUrl: String!
  locationName: String!
  Owner: User! @connection
  attendies: [User!] @connection
  photos: [Photo]
  organization: Organization
  comments: [Comment] @connection
}



type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  user: User! @connection
  event: Event! @connection
  text: String!
}
```

The queries i performed are:

**List Events**

```
query listEvents {
  listEvents {
    items {
      title
      Owner {
        username
      }
      comments {
        items{
          text
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**which brings back:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "listEvents": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "second Event",
          "Owner": {
            "username": "likono"
          },
          "comments": {
            "items": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**and List Comments**

```
query listComment{
  listComments{
    items{
      text
      event {
        title
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**which brings back**

```
{
  "data": {
    "listComments": {
      "items": [
        {
          "text": "Second Comment Same User Same Event",
          "event": {
            "title": "second Event",
            "id": "8bd6656b-b307-4e8f-ba65-84f75a4c2298"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there is a bi-directional relationship here. An event has comments, and a comment has an event. Can you try adding the name argument to your connection directive? E.g. 'comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "EventComments") and 'event: Event! @connection(name: "EventComments")'

Source: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/graphql-transform-tutorial.md#named-connections

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The cli brings an error when pushing to the cloud when i add the name directive. It does push when i remove the name directive. Thank you.

Comment: It worked after deleting the api and creating the api once again from scratch. Thank you for the help.